# Referrals from link aren't counting for new users

Tags: support, area-51, referrals

I recently joined - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3659/the-great-outdoors

I sent the link out to all of my friends.  A few joined.  Referral count 0.  I decided to get my wife to do it.  Referral count 0.  She un-committed and recommitted using the link (again), referral count 1.

My conclusion right now is that something in the newbie account creation loses track of where the referral is coming from.  I watched her through the whole process and she used the link to get there to sign up, but the referral only counted when she re-committed after the fact.

Comment: I just had the second friend un-commit and recommit and my count is now 2.  They signed up before my wife, so that confirms that the initial commit with a new users isn't counting for referrals.

Comment: Third user who did it went through with no problem.  User was much more technically savvy than the first two.  Secondary theory is that there's a condition built it that holds on the email confirmation, but I'm not sure that explains the first two.

Comment: Appears to be working as of today.

Answer (score 1):

Commitments are not counted until a user confirms their email address.  To keep it consistent, referrals aren't counted either unless a user confirms their email address.  I believe that is what happened here.